# How to prevent duplicate variable from changing together with actual variable?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

This is the issue:

```
if (commItems[0].CardNO == "" && commItems[0].Serial == "")
{               
    gridCommsItem.ItemsSource = commItems;
    tempGrid = gridCommsItem;
    gridCommsItem.Columns.Clear();
        .
        .
        .
}
```

Basically I have `2 datagrid`. 
1 actual datagrid "gridCommsItem" and a duplicate datagrid "tempGrid". Before I do gridCommsItem.Columns.Clear(), I want store all properties of gridCommsItem in tempGrid so I can restore conveniently in later codes.

However, through setting a breakpoint, I have found out that `IMMEDIATELY` after executing the line `"gridCommsItem.Columns.Clear();"`, tempGrid also updated along with gridCommsItem; all columns cleared! How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

> I have found out that IMMEDIATELY after executing the line gridCommsItem.Columns.Clear();

It looks like that you have bound your second grid, with gridCommsItem source. That is why clearing the gridCommsItem clears the other grid as well.

> I want store all properties of gridCommsItem in tempGrid so I can
>   restore conveniently in later codes.

I would recommend that you store all the properties in some sort of xml file for later restorage, instead of saving the complete grid.

Comment: Why and how can I prevent that? `gridCommsItem.ItemsSource = commItems;` `tempGrid = gridCommsItem;`

If I have set gridCommsItem.ItemSource to be commItems, then after assigning gridCommsItem to tempGrid, tempGrid.ItemSource should also be commItems and not gridCommsItem.

Comment: source is assigned by reference, hence your situation. i have recommended the possible solution as well in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid are pass by reference and not pass by value; hence, when you clear one variable, you are actually clearing the original data grid which is referenced by another variable; hence, both variables now contain nothing.

To avoid this, you'll have to do a deep copy of the data structure. You would need to copy the contents.

Have a look at the link below; it explains how to do it. Snippet from the link

```
private void copyDgv1ValueToDgv2()
        {
            //using import method to copy the datatable of dgv1 to dgv2
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                f2.dt2.ImportRow(dt.Rows[i]);
            }

            //or to manually copy the data rows of dgv1 to dgv2 using this method
            /*for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                f2.dt2.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            }*/
        }
```

Link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fe0539b0-a436-4a04-85cc-b05d111befba/passing-datagridview-values-to-datagridview-in-another-form?forum=winformsdatacontrols

Answer (score 0):

This Code may help you.
you need to copy all properties and create a clone object of main gridComms

```
static public void CloneObject(object dest, object src)
    {
        Type t = src.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
        {
            if (pi.CanWrite)
            {
                pi.SetValue(dest, pi.GetValue(src, null), null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Umm I'm not sure if I know how to use this. Do I just use CloneObject(tempGrid, gridCommItem) and restore later by simply using gridCommItem = tempGrid?

Comment: add this method to your class file and pass gridCommsItem as source and tempGrid as destination

Comment: These are what I have tried after adding the method:
(1)`CloneObject(tempGrid, gridCommItem);`
`gridCommItem = tempGrid;`

-nothing happen to tempGrid.

(2)Rewrote the method to return 'dest' and I use `tempGrid = CloneObject(tempGrid, gridCommItem);`

-nothing happen to tempGrid either